# Excel bar chart with two y axis & split areas

Tags: excel, charts

I have data like this.
[source table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwICE.png)

I would like to make a bar chart like below.
[Chart I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AA0SG.png)

The problem is that since Dioxin ranges are way smaller than the others, 
I can't look at the dioxin data properly.
In order to solve this problem, I would like to separate the chart areas into two and make a line between two areas with ranges of Dioxin shown in the right y axis.

How do I do this?

Comment: What have you tried? I don't think you can do that line in between without adding it as a single series and formatting the plot. The rest is a 2 Y axis bar plot with Dioxin on secondary axis.

Comment: Create two separate charts (the first one zeroes for Dioxin and the second one just for Dioxin with real values) and then for the Dioxin one, remove the border and fill for the chart area so that it is a transparent chart, then sit it on top of the first chart.  Yes, this is an ugly workaround, but it does work with a lot of find tuning

Comment: @CFO works a treat - did that with 6 different charts that looked like one...